# Delete current row data from grid

Tags: c#, .net

How can I delete the current row data from different tables in a gridview?

Comment: Can you elaborate? what data source your GridView is using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using `DataGridView` (not sure though), here's something you must have a look at.

Source : [Eggheadcafe](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10262938/delete-selected-rows-from-data-grid-view-and-update-table.aspx)

Just a **code snippet** :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
  System.Collections.ArrayList alv = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
  int i = 0;
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
  OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=<<Your Database Path>>");
  OleDbCommand cmd=new OleDbCommand();
  for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
    DataGridViewRow MyRow = dataGridView1.Rows[i];
    if (MyRow.Selected == true)
    {
    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
    try
    {
      conn.Open();
      //Here It Will Delete your Row From The Database Depending On Your Id....
      cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM MyTable Where Id=" + i + "";
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      conn.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    }
  }
  }
}
```